# How to decrypt password on Server-Side using GWT and RPC

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, gwt

iam using [gwt-crypto](https://github.com/mooreds/gwt-crypto/) for decrypting a password.
It works fine on the client side but if i try to enrypt a password on the server side, it doesnt work.
This is the method for the decryption which works fine on the client side but not on the server side.

```
private  static String decryptPasswort(String pw){

    byte[]GWT_DES_KEY = new byte[] { -110, 121, -65, 22, -60, 61, -22, 
            -60, 21, -122, 41, -89, -89, -68, -8, 41, -119, -51, -12, -36, 19, -8, -17, 47 };// StringResources.getGwtDesKey();

    TripleDesCipher cipher = new TripleDesCipher();
    cipher.setKey(GWT_DES_KEY);
    String dec ="";

    try {
        dec = cipher.decrypt(pw); // <=== ******here is the error*******
    } catch (DataLengthException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (InvalidCipherTextException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return dec;
}
```

Eclipse gives the following exception message:

> com.googlecode.gwt.crypto.bouncycastle.DataLengthException: last block incomplete in decryption
>       at com.googlecode.gwt.crypto.bouncycastle.paddings.PaddedBufferedBlockCipher.doFinal(PaddedBufferedBlockCipher.java:296)
>       at com.googlecode.gwt.crypto.client.AbstractStreamCipher.decrypt(AbstractStreamCipher.java:73)
>       at com.score.pics.server.GAEDatastoreServiceImpl.decryptPasswort(GAEDatastoreServiceImpl.java:284)
>       at com.score.pics.server.GAEDatastoreServiceImpl.passwordForgotten(GAEDatastoreServiceImpl.java:255)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
>       at com.google.appengine.tools.development.agent.runtime.Runtime.invoke(Runtime.java:130)
>       at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RPC.invokeAndEncodeResponse(RPC.java:561)
>       at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RemoteServiceServlet.processCall(RemoteServiceServlet.java:265)
>       at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RemoteServiceServlet.processPost(RemoteServiceServlet.java:305)
>       at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.AbstractRemoteServiceServlet.doPost(AbstractRemoteServiceServlet.java:62)
>       at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:637)
>       at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
>       at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:511)
>       at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1166)
>       at com.google.appengine.api.socket.dev.DevSocketFilter.doFilter(DevSocketFilter.java:74)
>       at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
>       at com.google.appengine.tools.development.ResponseRewriterFilter.doFilter(ResponseRewriterFilter.java:127)
>       at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
>       at com.google.appengine.tools.development.HeaderVerificationFilter.doFilter(HeaderVerificationFilter.java:34)
>       at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
>       at com.google.appengine.api.blobstore.dev.ServeBlobFilter.doFilter(ServeBlobFilter.java:63)
>       at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
>       at com.google.apphosting.utils.servlet.TransactionCleanupFilter.doFilter(TransactionCleanupFilter.java:43)
>       at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
>       at com.google.appengine.tools.development.StaticFileFilter.doFilter(StaticFileFilter.java:125)
>       at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
>       at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerModulesFilter.doDirectRequest(DevAppServerModulesFilter.java:366)
>       at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerModulesFilter.doDirectModuleRequest(DevAppServerModulesFilter.java:349)
>       at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerModulesFilter.doFilter(DevAppServerModulesFilter.java:116)
>       at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
>       at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:388)
>       at org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216)
>       at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:182)
>       at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:765)
>       at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:418)
>       at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppEngineWebAppContext.handle(DevAppEngineWebAppContext.java:98)
>       at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
>       at com.google.appengine.tools.development.JettyContainerService$ApiProxyHandler.handle(JettyContainerService.java:503)
>       at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
>       at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:326)
>       at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:542)
>       at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.content(HttpConnection.java:938)
>       at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:755)
>       at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:218)
>       at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:404)
>       at org.mortbay.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:409)
>       at org.mortbay.thread.QueuedThreadPool$PoolThread.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:582)

How can i encrypt something on the server side?

Comment: Please use server side encryption API to encrypt your password. Make RPC from client to server and perform encryption on server.

Comment: Please define "doesn't work" and post the code of your try

Comment: sorry it should be encrypting and not decrypting. the method encrypt works very fine server side